# python csv file frequency count

Tags: python, csv

i have csv file which contain id name and abstract  and some bacteria name. I have to find the frequency of bacteria (Bac1, Bac2 ... ) in abstract columns and save it in the file with column ID ,Date,

Example of my file csv:

```
ID  Date    Abstract                  Bac1      Bac2    Bac3
            research of the 
            vegetative organs 
            of the fendleri , 

3045 2018   cytoplasmatic hybrid 
            in vitro plants 
            containing the Brassicax

3046 2018   chloroplasts had been 
            conducted in comparison 
            to the parental forms.

3047 2018   It was found, that the
            anatomical structure 
            of the cybrid
```

Comment: Is this the actual format? CSV stands for “comma-separated values”, and I don't think these are comma-separated. In any case, please show the code you have so far and **the expected output** for this input.

Comment: it is csv file i have just created it as a sample

Comment: The point is, this is not a csv file, at least not any common version of it.

Comment: just forget the above sample i have csv file and  i have to find the frequency of bac1 , bac2  and so on in abstract column

Comment: The input csv file only has 3 columns ID, Date, Abstract. Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [mcve],  [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: no sir it is aprox  2205 and abtsract is aprox 61000

Comment: Your question is a too broad. [`str.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.count) might be useful, and the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module for iterating over the rows

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like below

```
with open(filename.csv, 'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    words=line.split(',')
    bac1_count=words[2].count(bac1)
    bac2_count=words[2].count(bac1)
    bac3_count=words[2].count(bac1)
    words.append(bac1_count, bac2_count, bac3_count)
    print(','.join(words))
```